# Spoofing IP: TCP connect

Tags: python, ip, tcp

Возможно ли сделать такую цепочку соединения и передачу пакетов: `я->мой прокси сервер->обычный сервер->я`?

т.е., мне нужно, чтобы обычный сервер отсылал сразу на меня без прокси.

Соединение tcp, реально ли это реализовать через ip spoofing?

Comment: Такое практикуют на стороне сервера (см Direct Server Return), но это требует специальной настройки прокси и собственно серверов. А то что вы хотите выглядит несколько странным

Comment: основным сервером я не владею.. только прокси...